# how to logout 2 users in git (two of the same users are logged in)

Tags: git

i am playing with git on mac and i did commit the first time and couldnt figure out how to save my commit so i closed the console then re-opened console and went back to commit again i did git status and i see myself logged in twice. and it says to press enter to continue and when i do i keep going back to the commit page to enter my comments im kind of in a loop and cant get out.

this is what i see

```
 0:32  up  1:47, 2 users, load averages: 0.20 0.24 0.26
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@  IDLE WHAT
sarmenhb console  -                Thu22    1:46 -
sarmenhb s000     -                 0:18       - w
```

here is the commit page. 
[image]

i see this when i do :w (to save)
it says for me to type :!w to override and when i do that i see myself logged in twice.
what do i do? i am really stuck

thanks

Comment: Try just quitting without saving (:q!), and then `git commit` again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do what your editor tells you: type `:w!` and override the existing commit message. Then, your commit will work.

I don't know that much about mac stuff, but I'm sure that `git status` doesn't give the output that you posted. You are logged in on two different TTYs and on the `console` TTY, your commit dialog is still open. Therefore, Vim refuses to write the commit message because it's still open in your `console` session.

Also, you don't *log in* to git. You are logged in on two TTYs.